# stat_smooth gam not the same as gam {mgcv}

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, gam, mgcv

I was using the `stat_smooth` function in `ggplot2`, decided I wanted the "goodness of fit", and used a mgcv GAM for that. It occurred to me that I should check to make sure that they were the same model (`stat_smooth` vs mgcv's `gam`), so I used the code below to check.

Seemingly, they have different results, as evidenced by the plot ([Plot: `stat_smoother` gam (red), mgcv `gam` (black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xpFv.png)).  However, I don't know why they have different results.  Is it that some default parameter is different between the two?  Is is that `gam· is being run on a numeric x and ·stat_smooth· is being run with a POSIXct x (if so - I don't know what to do about that). It looks like` stat_smooth` is smoother, but the k values are the same...

I think there are several posts on how to plot gam outputs in `ggplot2`, but I'd really like to know why `stat_smooth` and mgcv are giving different results in the first place.  I am very new to GAMs (and R), so it's quite possible I'm missing something easy.  However, I did google and search this forum before asking.

My data is a bit big to easily share, so I used a sample dataset - I've put the source in the code, as well as a `dput()` below everything, and my `sessionInfo()` after that.

I have tried to make a quality question, but it is only my second one.  Ever. So, constructive criticism is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(mgcv)

stackOF_data <- read_excel("mean-daily-flow-cumecs-vatnsdals.xlsx", sheet = "Data")
stackOF_data <- data.table(stackOF_data)
stackOF_data <- stackOF_data[,.(timeseries=as.POSIXct(Date,format("%Y-%m-%d")),mdf)]

a <- stackOF_data[,.(x=as.numeric(timeseries),y=mdf)]
a1 <- gam(y~s(x, k=100, bs="cs"),data=a) 
a2=data.table(gam_mdf= predict(a1,a))
a2=cbind(timeseries=stackOF_data$timeseries,a2)

# see if predict and actual are the same
p <- ggplot() + 
geom_line(data = a2, aes(x = timeseries, y = gam_mdf), size=1)+
scale_color_manual(values=c("black","magenta"))+
scale_y_continuous()+
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"), breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week")+ 
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=50, size=10,hjust=1))+
stat_smooth(data = stackOF_data, aes(x = (timeseries), y = mdf),method="gam", formula=y~s(x,k=100, bs="cs"), col="red", se=FALSE, size=1)
p

# data from: https://datamarket.com/data/set/235m/mean-daily-flow-cumecs-vatnsdalsa-river-1-jan-1972-31-dec-1974#!ds=235m&display=line&s=14l

> dput(a)
structure(list(x = c(126230400, 126316800, 126403200, 126489600, 
126576000, 126662400, 126748800, 126835200, 126921600, 127008000, 
127094400, 127180800, 127267200, 127353600, 127440000, 127526400, 
127612800, 127699200, 127785600, 127872000, 127958400, 128044800, 
128131200, 128217600, 128304000, 128390400, 128476800, 128563200, 
128649600, 128736000, 128822400, 128908800, 128995200, 129081600, 
129168000, 129254400, 129340800, 129427200, 129513600, 129600000, 
129686400, 129772800, 129859200, 129945600, 130032000, 130118400, 
130204800, 130291200, 130377600, 130464000, 130550400, 130636800, 
130723200, 130809600, 130896000, 130982400, 131068800, 131155200, 
131241600, 131328000, 131414400, 131500800, 131587200, 131673600, 
131760000, 131846400, 131932800, 132019200, 132105600, 132192000, 
132278400, 132364800, 132451200, 132537600, 132624000, 132710400, 
132796800, 132883200, 132969600, 133056000, 133142400, 133228800, 
133315200, 133401600, 133488000, 133574400, 133660800, 133747200, 
133833600, 133920000, 134006400, 134092800, 134179200, 134265600, 
134352000, 134438400, 134524800, 134611200, 134697600, 134784000, 
134870400, 134956800, 135043200, 135129600, 135216000, 135302400, 
135388800, 135475200, 135561600, 135648000, 135734400, 135820800, 
135907200, 135993600, 136080000, 136166400, 136252800, 136339200, 
136425600, 136512000, 136598400, 136684800, 136771200, 136857600, 
136944000, 137030400, 137116800, 137203200, 137289600, 137376000, 
137462400, 137548800, 137635200, 137721600, 137808000, 137894400, 
137980800, 138067200, 138153600, 138240000, 138326400, 138412800, 
138499200, 138585600, 138672000, 138758400, 138844800, 138931200, 
139017600, 139104000, 139190400, 139276800, 139363200, 139449600, 
139536000, 139622400, 139708800, 139795200, 139881600, 139968000, 
140054400, 140140800, 140227200, 140313600, 140400000, 140486400, 
140572800, 140659200, 140745600, 140832000, 140918400, 141004800, 
141091200, 141177600, 141264000, 141350400, 141436800, 141523200, 
141609600, 141696000, 141782400, 141868800, 141955200, 142041600, 
142128000, 142214400, 142300800, 142387200, 142473600, 142560000, 
142646400, 142732800, 142819200, 142905600, 142992000, 143078400, 
143164800, 143251200, 143337600, 143424000, 143510400, 143596800, 
143683200, 143769600, 143856000, 143942400, 144028800, 144115200, 
144201600, 144288000, 144374400, 144460800, 144547200, 144633600, 
144720000, 144806400, 144892800, 144979200, 145065600, 145152000, 
145238400, 145324800, 145411200, 145497600, 145584000, 145670400, 
145756800, 145843200, 145929600, 146016000, 146102400, 146188800, 
146275200, 146361600, 146448000, 146534400, 146620800, 146707200, 
146793600, 146880000, 146966400, 147052800, 147139200, 147225600, 
147312000, 147398400, 147484800, 147571200, 147657600, 147744000, 
147830400, 147916800, 148003200, 148089600, 148176000, 148262400, 
148348800, 148435200, 148521600, 148608000, 148694400, 148780800, 
148867200, 148953600, 149040000, 149126400, 149212800, 149299200, 
149385600, 149472000, 149558400, 149644800, 149731200, 149817600, 
149904000, 149990400, 150076800, 150163200, 150249600, 150336000, 
150422400, 150508800, 150595200, 150681600, 150768000, 150854400, 
150940800, 151027200, 151113600, 151200000, 151286400, 151372800, 
151459200, 151545600, 151632000, 151718400, 151804800, 151891200, 
151977600, 152064000, 152150400, 152236800, 152323200, 152409600, 
152496000, 152582400, 152668800, 152755200, 152841600, 152928000, 
153014400, 153100800, 153187200, 153273600, 153360000, 153446400, 
153532800, 153619200, 153705600, 153792000, 153878400, 153964800, 
154051200, 154137600, 154224000, 154310400, 154396800, 154483200, 
154569600, 154656000, 154742400, 154828800, 154915200, 155001600, 
155088000, 155174400, 155260800, 155347200, 155433600, 155520000, 
155606400, 155692800, 155779200, 155865600, 155952000, 156038400, 
156124800, 156211200, 156297600, 156384000, 156470400, 156556800, 
156643200, 156729600, 156816000, 156902400, 156988800, 157075200, 
157161600, 157248000, 157334400, 157420800, 157507200, 157593600, 
157680000), y = c(4.65, 4.65, 4.65, 4.48, 5.16, 5.52, 5.34, 5.34, 
4.82, 4.65, 4.48, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.14, 3.82, 3.98, 3.98, 4.31, 
5.71, 6.5, 6.3, 5.71, 5.71, 5.16, 4.65, 4.14, 3.98, 4.48, 4.48, 
4.31, 4.65, 4.31, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.82, 3.67, 
3.67, 3.98, 3.98, 3.82, 3.82, 3.82, 4.14, 5.9, 4.48, 3.98, 3.98, 
3.82, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 4.65, 3.98, 4.31, 4.31, 3.67, 4.31, 6.1, 
7.3, 7.5, 7.5, 8.14, 10.8, 16.1, 14.8, 12.5, 9.9, 8.14, 6.9, 
6.1, 5.34, 5.16, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 5.52, 6.3, 7.3, 6.9, 
5.9, 5.71, 5.71, 8.58, 31.5, 33.7, 18.4, 11.3, 16.1, 32.9, 45.3, 
54, 25.7, 18, 15.9, 15.6, 14.5, 15.9, 35.9, 37.5, 29.4, 27.5, 
30.1, 27.5, 30.8, 29.4, 22, 20.1, 35.9, 36.7, 32.9, 22, 18, 15.9, 
15.2, 14.8, 13, 12.7, 12.5, 11, 9.68, 8.8, 7.92, 7.3, 6.9, 7.3, 
10.3, 11, 11.3, 11.9, 12.5, 13.6, 12.2, 10.8, 9.9, 9.46, 8.8, 
7.5, 7.1, 7.71, 7.1, 6.1, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 5.52, 5.52, 6.3, 
6.7, 6.5, 5.9, 5.71, 5.9, 5.71, 5.52, 7.3, 7.5, 7.1, 7.3, 6.7, 
6.9, 7.3, 7.5, 10.8, 11.6, 8.58, 7.92, 7.1, 6.7, 6.5, 6.1, 5.9, 
5.9, 5.71, 5.52, 5.52, 5.52, 5.9, 5.9, 5.71, 5.52, 5.52, 5.34, 
5.34, 5.52, 6.5, 6.5, 5.71, 5.34, 5.16, 4.99, 4.82, 4.82, 4.99, 
4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.65, 4.48, 4.48, 4.31, 4.31, 4.14, 
4.14, 4.31, 4.48, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.99, 5.71, 6.3, 6.1, 6.1, 
5.9, 5.71, 5.52, 5.52, 5.52, 5.52, 5.52, 5.34, 5.34, 5.52, 5.52, 
5.52, 5.34, 5.34, 5.52, 5.34, 5.52, 5.52, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 
5.71, 5.9, 6.3, 6.9, 7.5, 6.5, 6.1, 6.1, 5.9, 6.1, 6.1, 5.9, 
6.5, 6.5, 6.1, 5.9, 5.9, 5.71, 5.9, 5.9, 5.71, 4.99, 4.65, 5.16, 
5.34, 5.34, 4.65, 4.99, 5.71, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 4.99, 5.34, 
5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 5.52, 5.34, 5.52, 5.71, 6.5, 7.71, 6.9, 6.5, 
6.7, 6.1, 5.9, 6.1, 5.9, 5.71, 7.92, 7.71, 7.1, 7.92, 5.34, 5.16, 
8.14, 10.1, 7.92, 7.3, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 8.58, 7.3, 6.9, 7.3, 6.3, 
5.16, 6.1, 5.52, 4.99, 5.34, 5.34, 5.34, 5.16, 5.71, 5.52, 5.52, 
5.16, 4.82, 5.52, 6.1, 5.9, 5.71, 5.52, 5.16, 4.99, 4.48, 4.82, 
5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 4.82, 4.65, 3.82, 4.14, 4.65, 4.65, 
4.31, 4.31, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 4.99, 4.65, 5.16, 5.16, 
5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.16, 5.34, 5.34)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -365L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000005860788>)

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United         States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6 readxl_0.1.0     mgcv_1.8-7       nlme_3.1-121         scales_0.3.0     sos_1.3-8        brew_1.0-6       ggplot2_1.0.1   
[9] MASS_7.3-43     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      lattice_0.20-33  digest_0.6.8     chron_2.3-47     grid_3.2.2       plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5    
 [9] stringi_0.5-5    reshape2_1.4.1   Matrix_1.2-2     labeling_0.3     proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.2      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2   
[17] colorspace_1.2-6
```

**Partial Solution**

I still don't really know why the two methods are giving different answers, and that bothers me.  However, after much internet searching, I did find the following workaround:

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(mgcv)

stackOF_data <- read_excel("C:/Users/jel4049/Desktop/mean-daily-flow-cumecs-    vatnsdals.xlsx", sheet = "Data")
stackOF_data <- data.table(stackOF_data)

stackOF_data <- stackOF_data[,.(timeseries=as.POSIXct(Date,format("%Y-%m-%d")),mdf)]
a <- stackOF_data[,.(x=as.numeric(timeseries),y=mdf)]
a1 <- gam(y~s(x, k=100, bs="cs"),data=a) 
a2=data.table(gam_mdf = predict(a1,a))

preds <- predict(a1,se.fit=TRUE)
my_data <- data.frame(mu=preds$fit, low =(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit), high = (preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit))


m <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = a2, aes(x=stackOF_data$timeseries, y=gam_mdf), size=1, col="blue")+
  geom_smooth(data=my_data,aes(ymin = low, ymax = high, x=stackOF_data$timeseries, y = mu), stat = "identity", col="green")
m
```

Now at least I know that the summary and data fit quality info I can get from some of the mgcv functions match my plots.

Comment: @aosmith  Thank you for the response.  It throws the error `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`  It seems to be a difference in the requirements of `gam` vs `stat_smooth` in terms of what kind of date/time info they can accept.  I am not sure how to make them the same, and still have my plot with a readable x-axis....Happy to have help on that, if you have any ideas!  Thanks.

Comment: @aosmith  I have been working on this.  I tried:

Comment: @aosmith  I have been working on this.  I tried: `w <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = a2, aes(x=a$x, y=gam_mdf), size=1, col="blue")+
  geom_smooth(data = a, aes(x=x, y=y),method="gam", formula=y~s(x,k=100, bs="cs"), col="green",se=FALSE, size=1)
w`  That should be more like what you were thinking, right?  The plot still shows a difference.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for having another look. I still would love to know why they don't match up.  However, I did find a work around that I've included in my answer above.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out the differences you were seeing was because you were using the default for the `n` argument in `stat_smooth`.

From the help page:

> n  number of points to evaluate smoother at

Of course, it didn't jump out at me right away that this meant `n` controls the size of the dataset for the `newdata` argument in `predict` and therefore `stat_smooth` doesn't use the original dataset when making the predictions.  But I was reading this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173779/2461552) on a different `stat_smooth` question and realized that to figure out what was going on I should take a closer look at the `stat_smooth` predictions vs manual predictions from a fitted `gam` model.

So, using your dataset from your OP, which I named `dat`, we can check what's going on.

The plot when `k = 100`, after fitting the model via `gam` and adding the predictions to the dataset.  As you noted, the blue (`stat_smooth`) and black (manual predictions) don't match.

```
dat$predgam = predict(gam(y ~ s(x, k = 100), data = dat))

(p1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 100)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predgam)))
```

[image]

You can always use `ggplot_build` to look at your plot object and see all the pieces that make it up (I'm not showing the results here because it takes up so much space, but the output will print to your Console).

`ggplot_build(p1)`

The prediction dataset for `stat_smooth` is the second in the list of datasets.

`ggplot_build(p1)$data[[2]]`

But look how many rows that dataset has:

```
nrow(ggplot_build(p1)$data[[2]])
[1] 80
```

The default setting for the `n` argument is 80, but you have 365 rows in your dataset.  So what happens if you change `n` to 365?  I'll make the smooth line fatter so you can actually see it (in blue).

```
(p2 = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 100), n = 365, size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predgam)))
```

[image]

```
nrow(ggplot_build(p2)$data[[2]])
[1] 365
```

If you look at the code for the `predictdf` function mentioned in the Details section of the `stat_smooth` help page you'll see that the original dataset isn't used when making predictions.  Instead, a sequence is made from the original explanatory variable.  This is something that can be really important when working with a small dataset and you need more prediction points in order for the line to look smooth.  In your case, though, the original dataset is already a nice smooth sequence of `x` so using `n = 365` gets the same predictions from `stat_smooth` as the original dataset does.

You can see the code for `predictdf` [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth-methods.r).

Comment: What does 'k' mean here: y ~ s(x, k = 100) ?

Comment: @Kshitij15571 See the documentation for `s()` to see the argument descriptions, `?mgcv::s`.  Description of the argument starts with " 
the dimension of the basis used to represent the smooth term."

Comment: I believe the issue may be with the plotting in  `plot.gam() `  or  `plot(model) `  . The partial solution by @CJ9 fixes it, otherwise the curve does not fit well the data. See here for the same outcome using the OP solution stackoverflow.com/a/67096214/2291642 . Changing  `n ` did not change the output, at least in my case.