# identify data points that fall outside CI in a correlation plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for the most efficient way to identify/extract data points that fall outside the CI shade in a correlation plot like this one:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~poly(x, 2), size = 1, se = T, level = 0.99)
```

[image: sample plot]

I would like to be able to save a new variable which marks the data points that fall outside as follows:

```
    x     y      group
1:  0.0  0.00     1
2:  0.5  0.40     1
3:  0.9  0.70     1
4:  1.0  1.30     1
5:  2.0  6.60     0
6:  3.0  3.10     1
7:  4.0  4.40     1
8:  5.0  5.90     1
9:  6.0  6.05     1
10: 7.0  7.60     1
11: 8.0  8.00     1
12: 9.0  2.90     0
13: 10.0 13.80    1
14: 11.0 13.40    1
15: 12.0 14.90    1
```

**Original Data:**

```
df <- data.table("x"=c(0,0.5,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
      "y"=c(0,0.4,0.7,1.3,6.6,3.1,4.4,5.9,6.05,7.6,8,2.9,13.8,13.4,14.9))
```

**Desired Data:**

```
df2 <- data.table("x"=c(0,0.5,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
       "y"=c(0,0.4,0.7,1.3,6.6,3.1,4.4,5.9,6.05,7.6,8,2.9,13.8,13.4,14.9), 
       "group" = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find points over and under the confidence interval when using geom\_stat / geom\_smooth in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082901/find-points-over-and-under-the-confidence-interval-when-using-geom-stat-geom-s)

Comment: perfect! thanks @neilfws

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you can do this using ggplot. But you can also rerun the `lm` regression and deduce the points outside the confidence interval from there.

```
df$group=rep(1,nrow(df))
lm1=lm(y~poly(x,2),df)
p1=predict(lm1,interval="confidence",level=0.99)
df$group[df$y<p1[,2] | df$y>p1[,3]]=0
```

Comment: this is great. nice and simple to follow what's being done. thank you @Lamia

Answer (score 3):

First we would run a linear model `lm()` on your data corresponding to your smoothed fit. `x + I(x^2)` is the same thing as `poly(x, 2)`, just written out. Then we `augment` the original data with the predictions from that model, which will be columns named `.fitted, .resid, .se.fit`. Then we can make a new variable called `group` where it's a logical test: is the distance between the observed `y` and the predicted `.fitted` greater than 2.58 times the standard error of the fit? This roughly corresponds to your 99% confidence interval from the smoothed line.

```
require(broom)
require(dplyr)

df %>% 
  do(augment(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = .))) %>%
  mutate(group = as.numeric(abs(y - .fitted) > 2.58*.se.fit))
```

For funsies, we can view your data, and just color the points differently by that `group` variable:

```
df %>% 
  do(augment(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = .))) %>%
  mutate(group = as.numeric(abs(y - .fitted) < 2.58*.se.fit)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(group)), size = 4) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1, level = .99)
```

[image]

---

## Edited to clarify

The question asked about the 99% CI. I mistakenly had "3" as the z-score to mark points outside the confidence interval. It is actually `2.58*.se.fit`. For the 95% CI, it would be 1.96 (~2).

Comment: neat, though a little too advanced for me to fully understand the steps, but thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it a bit hastily. I'll edit it with comments.

Comment: @Brian Hi Brian, I could not understand in your answer the part about `the observed y and the predicted .fitted greater than 3 times the standard error of the fit? This roughly corresponds to your 99% confidence interval from the smoothed line.`. What is the `?` mean and How can we decide 95% confidence interval multiplier in this aspect ?

Comment: The predicted value `.fitted` is the model's estimate of the mean at each value of `x`. The standard error of the mean is output from the model as `.se.fit`. For normally distributed variables, the 95% confidence interval is mean +/- 2.96*SE. If you look at the value `abs(y-.fitted)` that tells you how far away the data was from the model fit. If that distance is `< 3*.se.fit` then that datapoint is within the 95% CI.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the answer. I am little bit lost in here.  I look at the data and checked `abs(y-.fitted)` . If I put 2.96*SE to group one of the data in the top right side is outside of the CI 95%. I don't know you mis-typed 2.96 or not? because in [here] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)  in the table it is saying the number should be 1.96? I still cannot understand where this 3 came from in your solution?

Comment: The 2.96 was from me mixing up the 95% and 99% confidence intervals. The z-score for 99% is 2.58 and for 95% is 1.96. Thanks for catching my error!

Comment: @Brian No problem. Thanks for the correction and your answer to this question. It is very useful for me:)