# Plot multiple lines and add an overall confidence band over these lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
test_data <-
  data.frame(
    var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
    var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    var2 = 250 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10)))
  )
```

Given the above test data, I would like to do the following:

(1) plot the lines similar to this: [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

(2) add an overall confidence band for these lines (lines can be seen as points), similar to this: [Find points over and under the confidence interval when using geom_stat / geom_smooth in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082901/find-points-over-and-under-the-confidence-interval-when-using-geom-stat-geom-s)

I know how to do them separately but not sure how to combine them in a single plot.

Comment: Take the "general approach" [as in this answer to plotting multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777592/903061), then add `geom_smooth` with the color aesthetic set to NULL.

Comment: Please add the code you've used for the separate plots to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743503/how-to-add-shaded-confidence-intervals-to-line-plot-with-specified-values/29747072) you can check one of the answers were `geom_ribbon` is used instead of `geom_line`. This should answer (2). With respect to (1), it could be plotted the same way as you said in the link you mentioned.

Lets assume that you want to keep var0 in the x axis, and plot with respect to var1 and var2.

To do this you have to first gather var1 and var2

```
test_data <-
  data.frame(
    var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
    var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    var2 = 250 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10)))
  ) %>%
  gather(key="var",value="value",var1:var2)
```

This yields as follows:

```
> head(test_data)
       var0  var    value
1 100.00000 var1 150.0000
2  85.67636 var1 146.4407
3  76.86862 var1 151.6061
4  79.46151 var1 143.6943
5  96.86709 var1 147.8999
6  91.20310 var1 157.2294
```

Now, to plot accordingly, you'd have to plot by the new group variable "var" (contanining names of groups "var1" and "var2"), plotting a ribbon `geom_ribbon` for upper and lower bounds, and a `geom_line`call for plotting the actual line.

```
test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var0,y=value,group=var)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=value*0.95,ymax=value*1.05),fill="grey70") +
  geom_line()
```

This yields:

[image: Plot]